# jQuery - Generalizing code so it works with any number of slides

Tags: jquery

I'm adding some extra functionality to a slider, basically making the caption clickable so it links to the same page as the slider image. I managed to do it using jQuery, but I'm not sure how to generalize so it would work with any number of slides. Here is the code I use for two slides:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".caption-wrap:eq(0)").append("<a href=\""+$("ul[class=\"slides\"] > li > a:eq(0)").attr("href")+"\"><span class=\"clickable\"></span></a>");
    $(".caption-wrap:eq(1)").append("<a href=\""+$("ul[class=\"slides\"] > li > a:eq(1)").attr("href")+"\"><span class=\"clickable\"></span></a>");
});

<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <a href="test1">...</a>
        <div class="caption-wrap">...</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="test2">...</a>
        <div class="caption-wrap">...</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to append a span with the corresponding link to the "caption-wrap" div.

This is probably a simple question, but I'm relatively new to jQuery. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you would need to show the structure of the html so that we can help. what you could do is store a data attribute on the slide (something like `data-link="whatever"`, loop through the captions (set a class for all the captions) and set the link as the data attribute of the slide.

Comment: And the html looks like...?

Comment: @ArvindSridharan sorry, there it is

Comment: You can just use $('.caption-wrap').append(...);

Comment: @mrmoment but how can I assign the specific link I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```js
var $slides = $('ul.slides > li > a');
$(".caption-wrap").append(function(idx) {
  return '<a href="' + $slides.eq(idx).attr("href") + '"><span class="clickable"></span></a>';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <a href="test1">...</a>
    <div class="caption-wrap">...</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="test2">...</a>
    <div class="caption-wrap">...</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Or simpler

```js
$(".caption-wrap").append(function(idx) {
  return '<a href="' + $(this).prev('a').attr("href") + '"><span class="clickable"></span></a>';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <a href="test1">...</a>
    <div class="caption-wrap">...</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="test2">...</a>
    <div class="caption-wrap">...</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to current code structure (generating a html page and call a document ready javascript function to form children elements of `div`s), you can try to add a for loop:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i=0; i<$("ul.slides li").length; i++){
        $(".caption-wrap:eq("+i+")").append("<a href=\""+$("ul[class=\"slides\"] > li > a:eq("+i+")").attr("href")+"\"><span class=\"clickable\"></span></a>");
    }
});
```

But you can also bind a event listener to the `div` elements and get the href of its sibling `a` tag.

Also, you can ... just add the DOM elements directly in the HTML codes?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes it easy to just grab a list of all the div's with the "caption-wrap" class and loop through them. You can then relatively reference nearby elements.

```js
$(document).on("ready", function() {
  /*Loop each of the caption divs*/
  $(".caption-wrap").each(function(i, e) {

    var this$ = $(this);
    /*Grab the link from the A element within the same li as the div*/
    var href = this$.siblings("a").attr("href");
    /*alternately this could be done as a data attribute on the div ie*/
    /*href = this$.attr("data-href");*/
    this$.append("<a href='" + href + "'><span class='clickable'>" + i + "</span></a>");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <a href="test1"></a>
    <div data-href="test1" class="caption-wrap"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="test2"></a>
    <div data-href="test2" class="caption-wrap"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```